# sqrt() VST-Plugin MATH - Loss gain by sqrt()?

Tags: math, signal-processing, vst

is it possible that a calculation with "sqrt()" has affect to the ouput gain?
Here's is my Code: (MS Tool with Panorama adjustment)

```
//Code...precalculations above

(*out1++) = (mid+side) * dGain * sqrt(dOne - dPan); //sqrt for pan law
(*out2++) = (mid-side) * dGain * sqrt(dOne);
```

Input/Output Gain is quiet a little different in this case.
Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related? http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4264576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but it seems that your algorithm is attempting to apply stereo panning laws to the left/right channels. In that case, I don't think that the calculation is being done correctly. This link (also posted in a comment) might be useful:

> http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4264576

If my suspicions are correct, then you are not applying the correct amount of gain compensation to the signal, which is why it's probably not sounding as you expect.